# call_user_func_array passing additional params to method

Tags: arrays, parameters

In `App.php` file I have this:

For URL like this one: `http://mywebroot/myapp/param1/param2`

```
    # anything leftover in $url, set as params, else empty.
    $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

    print_r($this->params); // this gives me dumped array values as it should
    // so I can see Array ( [0] => param1 [1] => param2 )

    // Now I am trying to pass that array to my controller:
    //
    //
    # call our method from requested controller, passing params if any to method
    call_user_func_array([
            $this->controller,
            $this->method

        ], $this->params); // Don't worry about `$this->controller`,
                        // `$this->method` part, it will end up calling method from the class bellow.
```

In my controller file I have:

```
class Home extends Controller {

    // here I am expecting to catch those params
    //
    public function index($params = []){

        var_dump($params); // This gives `string 'param1' (length=6)`? WHERE IS ARRAY?


        // not relevant for this question
        # request view, providing directory path, and sending along some vars
        $this->view('home/index', ['name' => $user->name]);

    }
```

So my question is, why in my controller I dont have that `$params` as array, but just first element of array.
If I instead do:

```
    public function index($param1, $param2){
```

I will have all of them, but I want flexibility in terms of how many of params I will get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `call_user_func` not `call_user_func_array`

`call_user_func` takes first parameter as `callable` and rest send as parameters to the function. While `call_user_func_array` expects exactly two parameters - first one is `callable` the second one is an array with parameters of the called function. See following example:

```
function my_func($one, $two = null) {
    var_dump($one);
    var_dump($two);
}

call_user_func('my_func', array('one', 'two'));
call_user_func_array('my_func', array('one', 'two'));
```

first (`call_user_func`) will dump:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=> string(3) "two" }
NULL
```

while the `call_user_func_array` will result in:

```
string(3) "one"
string(3) "two"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do with first one also, using `func_get_args()`, but still like your solution better, as it's cleaner.